Solved - port-forwarding to KVM VM on Ubuntu
I,m configuring port forwarding to KVM VM on Ubuntu 22.04.
I can connect to VM from outside of host server. But it failed from VM itself.
my host's IP : 222.222.222.222
vm's IP : 192.168.122.201

iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             222.222.222.222               tcp dpt:1023 to:192.168.122.201:22

I can connect to VM from outside host server.
ssh -p 1023 222.222.222.222  --> OK

But it failed from VM itself.
ssh -p 1023 222.222.222.222   --> failed!!
ssh: connect to host 222.222.222.222 port 1023: Connection timed out

From, host server it could be connnect itself after adding iptable rule.
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             222.222.222.222               tcp dpt:1023 to:192.168.122.201:22

I need to communicate to Host's IP from VM. Please help me~!
Updated : From VM, can connect to Host server thru host IP.

Please, post your solution as an answer (into the form below), and accept it yourself.

Solution : After setting POSTROUTING at nat table, the problem solved!!!
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.201 -j SNAT --to-source 222.222.222.222

To specify destination port, use internal port.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.201 -p tcp --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source 222.222.222.222

